# How to get credentials from KeyVault withput using secret key?

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, azure-keyvault

I have a keyvault which uses secret key to retreive the credentials in javascript. But my client doesnt want to use "VaultSettings.KeyVaultSettings.azureKeyVaultAccessKey" which is a secret value of the Application registered in Key vault portal.
Below is the code for accessing the credentials.

There is one method in C# AzureServiceTokenProvider() which gives a token that can be used to access the credentials in keyVault. Do we have something like this in node.js?

````
const AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;
let VaultSettings = require('./KeyVaultSettings');

class KeyVaultUtils {
    constructor(secretNameIdentifier, secretVersionIdentifier) {
            this.secretName = secretNameIdentifier;
            this.secretVersion = secretVersionIdentifier;
    }

    authenticator(challenge, callback) {
            var context = new AuthenticationContext(challenge.authorization);
            return context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(challenge.resource,
                VaultSettings.KeyVaultSettings.clientAppId,
                VaultSettings.KeyVaultSettings.azureKeyVaultAccessKey,
                function (err, tokenResponse) {
                if (err) throw err;
                    var authorizationValue = tokenResponse.tokenType + ' ' + tokenResponse.accessToken;
                    return callback(null, authorizationValue);
                });
        }

        getKeyVaultValue(callback) {
            var credentials = new KeyVault.KeyVaultCredentials(this.authenticator);
            var client = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
            client.getSecret(VaultSettings.KeyVaultSettings.vaultUri, VaultSettings.KeyVaultSettings.azureAccount, VaultSettings.KeyVaultSettings.azureAccountKey)
                .then(function (result) {
                callback(result);
            });
        };
}
module.exports = { KeyVaultUtils };```
````

Comment: You'll need to use Managed Identity manually to do that. I think the docs had something on that way as well..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Key Vault with Azure Managed Service Identity in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630804/how-to-access-key-vault-with-azure-managed-service-identity-in-node)